# VueJS client cannot connect to Flask server

Tags: vue.js, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

So I'm creating an application that that uses SocketIO to stream a constant messages from the server (powered by Flask) to the client (powered by Vue). However, so far, I've been unsuccessful. Here is the minimal setup I used:

***app.py***

```
from flask import Flask
import eventlet
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

class CustomFlask(Flask):
    jinja_options = Flask.jinja_options.copy()
    jinja_options.update(dict(
        variable_start_string='{$',  # Default is '{{', I'm changing this because Vue.js uses '{{' / '}}'
        variable_end_string='$}',
    ))

app = CustomFlask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('testing')
def testing(msg):
    print(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

***App.vue***

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Test/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Test from './components/Test.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Test
  }
}
</script>
```

***Test.vue***

```
<template>
    <div>
        This is a test
        <button @click="testing">Test socket!</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Test',
        methods: {
            testing() {
                this.$socket.client.emit('testing', 'Test string')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

***main.js***

*This is the mount JS file for Vue*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueSocketIOExt  from 'vue-socket.io-extended';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port)
Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, socket);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  sockets: {
    testing() {
      console.log('Tested socket for client!')
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

***vue.config.js***

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/socket.io': {
                target: 'http://localhost:5000',
                ws: true,
                changeOrigin: true,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The errors I'm constantly getting when I check the console are:

1. `failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`
2. Basically a `400 (BAD REQUEST)` code on a `GET` request

Comment: Probably a cross-origin problem. You can enable logs on the server to see more information about the 400 error. Add `engineio_logger=True` to your `SocketIO()` constructor.

Comment: @Miguel I added the arg in the SocketIO constructor and one thing was always printing `http://localhost:8080 is not an accepted origin.` Does this mean I have to add a `cors_allowed_origins`?

Comment: But this is just for development. When deployed, the Flask server serves the build folder for the Vue App

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent versions of Flask-SocketIO come configured with the most secure settings with regards to cross-origins setup, which is to only allow the same origin. If your Vue app and your Flask app are running on different ports, then you have to configure cross-origin.

For example, if your Vue app is hosted at `http://localhost:8080`, you can allow that as an origin with:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='http://localhost:8080')
```